# Can't translate this particular symbol (Character identified: 启)

Tags: translation, characters, character-identification

I have this message on my Android phone. I tried to translate it using OCR tools and Google translate. But there's one symbol I can't find anywhere: it looks like "ṔA" (the 4th symbol at the top from left to right). Missing that symbol messes up the whole translation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

启, means 'start' or 'boot' in this scenario.

Comment: So the title says something like Making the boot faster by 30%?

Comment: Yes for the meaning, but I don't trust them. (The second half is only a joke to avoid the character limit.)

Comment: I haven't finish translating the second part i get a lot of "wood" and "knife". How come it's a joke? maybe it's a virus lol

Comment: It's hard to translate some of them even if I understand them. However at least I can serve as a more accurate OCR:'强化自启能力，手机提速30% 自启管理全新升级，强力禁止顽固自启 预装卸载更彻底，深度释放手机空间 Root管理更智能，准确判断权限合理性' if that helps.

Comment: 自启 = 自動啟動 = auto-start.

Answer (score 1):

strengthen self-running (management) ability，accelerate cellphone 30%

self-running management totally upgrade，deeply free spaces

ROOT-Management more intelligent ，Accurately judge （APP's） permissions(or 
authority,I don't know which one is being used)

btw,I think these 手机管家（XX助手，XX管家，XX卫士） are just occupy your space,slow your phone,steal your contacts and records。